# How to troubleshoot Apache client 5.0 "Connection is closed" HTTPS POST error

Tags: java, apache-httpcomponents, apache-httpasyncclient, apache-httpclient-5.x

I have a Tomcat server configured for HTTP1.1 and HTTP/2 on port 8002, and also HTTPS on port 8003 to allow me to test against. I am writing Java code using Apache HTTP Client 5.0 to talk HTTP/2 to the server and having issues. Ultimately, I want to be able to POST a message with content to the server using HTTP/2, but I'm having issues so I've stripped down my code to a simple example based on one of the Apache shipped examples - [H2TlsAlpnRequestExecutionExample](https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-core/blob/master/httpcore5-h2/src/test/java/org/apache/hc/core5/http2/examples/H2TlsAlpnRequestExecutionExample.java).

The given example is hitting the https://nghttp2.org using a GET request, and I can get that to work. Changing to a POST request also works - although you get a HTTP 405 (Method not allowed) response the call was made. If I point the exact same example to my server then I can GET and POST successfully to the regular HTTP/1.1 port (8002) using HTTP/2. However attempts to GET or POST to HTTPS on port 8003 fail - although GET/POST using HTTPv1.1 (rather then HTTP/2) work to HTTPS/8003 too.

With DEBUG on I don't see much debug info from the apache libraries, but I do see that my log messages saying my cert was trusted in both cases, so obviously some initial call negotiation is done.

This is the log for a HTTP2 call to nghttp2.org (which I see is using HTTP/2 from a line in the log):

```
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2021-03-04 12:37:29.021 GMT|SSLCipher.java:438|jdk.tls.keyLimits:  entry = AES/GCM/NoPadding KeyUpdate 2^37. AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE = 137438953472
0    [main] DEBUG com.test.HTTP2Tester  - Making requst to https://nghttp2.org:443
422  [main] INFO  com.test.HTTP2Tester  - Awaiting latch to countdown ....
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|0E|requester-dispatch-1|2021-03-04 12:37:30.345 GMT|SSLCipher.java:1840|KeyLimit read side: algorithm = AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE
countdown value = 137438953472
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|0E|requester-dispatch-1|2021-03-04 12:37:30.347 GMT|SSLCipher.java:1994|KeyLimit write side: algorithm = AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE
countdown value = 137438953472
725  [requester-dispatch-1] INFO  com.test.HTTP2Tester  - Trusting certificate from CN=nghttp2.org
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|0E|requester-dispatch-1|2021-03-04 12:37:30.378 GMT|SSLCipher.java:1840|KeyLimit read side: algorithm = AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE
countdown value = 137438953472
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|0E|requester-dispatch-1|2021-03-04 12:37:30.379 GMT|SSLCipher.java:1994|KeyLimit write side: algorithm = AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE
countdown value = 137438953472
942  [requester-dispatch-1] DEBUG com.test.HTTP2Tester  - 0 <<[type=4, flags=0, streamId=0, payoad=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=9 lim=33 cap=65545]]
943  [requester-dispatch-1] DEBUG com.test.HTTP2Tester  - 0 <<[type=4, flags=0, streamId=0, payoad=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=9 lim=33 cap=65545]]
958  [requester-dispatch-1] DEBUG com.test.HTTP2Tester  - nghttp2.org/139.162.123.134:443 (1) >> :method: POST
958  [requester-dispatch-1] DEBUG com.test.HTTP2Tester  - nghttp2.org/139.162.123.134:443 (1) >> :scheme: https
959  [requester-dispatch-1] DEBUG com.test.HTTP2Tester  - nghttp2.org/139.162.123.134:443 (1) >> :authority: nghttp2.org:443
959  [requester-dispatch-1] DEBUG com.test.HTTP2Tester  - nghttp2.org/139.162.123.134:443 (1) >> :path: /httpbin/ip
959  [requester-dispatch-1] DEBUG com.test.HTTP2Tester  - nghttp2.org/139.162.123.134:443 (1) >> user-agent: Apache-HttpCore/5.0.2 (Java/11.0.10)
966  [requester-dispatch-1] DEBUG com.test.HTTP2Tester  - 0 <<[type=4, flags=1, streamId=0, payoad=null]
966  [requester-dispatch-1] DEBUG com.test.HTTP2Tester  - 0 <<[type=4, flags=1, streamId=0, payoad=null]
1168 [requester-dispatch-1] DEBUG com.test.HTTP2Tester  - 1 <<[type=1, flags=4, streamId=1, payoad=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=9 lim=258 cap=65545]]
1169 [requester-dispatch-1] DEBUG com.test.HTTP2Tester  - 1 <<[type=1, flags=4, streamId=1, payoad=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=9 lim=258 cap=65545]]
1170 [requester-dispatch-1] DEBUG com.test.HTTP2Tester  - nghttp2.org/139.162.123.134:443 (1) << :status: 405
1170 [requester-dispatch-1] DEBUG com.test.HTTP2Tester  - nghttp2.org/139.162.123.134:443 (1) << date: Thu, 04 Mar 2021 12:37:30 GMT
1172 [requester-dispatch-1] DEBUG com.test.HTTP2Tester  - nghttp2.org/139.162.123.134:443 (1) << content-type: text/html
1173 [requester-dispatch-1] DEBUG com.test.HTTP2Tester  - nghttp2.org/139.162.123.134:443 (1) << allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
1173 [requester-dispatch-1] DEBUG com.test.HTTP2Tester  - nghttp2.org/139.162.123.134:443 (1) << content-length: 178
1173 [requester-dispatch-1] DEBUG com.test.HTTP2Tester  - nghttp2.org/139.162.123.134:443 (1) << access-control-allow-origin: *
1174 [requester-dispatch-1] DEBUG com.test.HTTP2Tester  - nghttp2.org/139.162.123.134:443 (1) << access-control-allow-credentials: true
1175 [requester-dispatch-1] DEBUG com.test.HTTP2Tester  - nghttp2.org/139.162.123.134:443 (1) << x-backend-header-rtt: 0.002696
1176 [requester-dispatch-1] DEBUG com.test.HTTP2Tester  - nghttp2.org/139.162.123.134:443 (1) << strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000
1176 [requester-dispatch-1] DEBUG com.test.HTTP2Tester  - nghttp2.org/139.162.123.134:443 (1) << server: nghttpx
1176 [requester-dispatch-1] DEBUG com.test.HTTP2Tester  - nghttp2.org/139.162.123.134:443 (1) << via: 1.1 nghttpx
1177 [requester-dispatch-1] DEBUG com.test.HTTP2Tester  - nghttp2.org/139.162.123.134:443 (1) << alt-svc: h3-29=":443"; ma=3600
1177 [requester-dispatch-1] DEBUG com.test.HTTP2Tester  - nghttp2.org/139.162.123.134:443 (1) << x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
1177 [requester-dispatch-1] DEBUG com.test.HTTP2Tester  - nghttp2.org/139.162.123.134:443 (1) << x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
1178 [requester-dispatch-1] DEBUG com.test.HTTP2Tester  - nghttp2.org/139.162.123.134:443 (1) << x-content-type-options: nosniff
1186 [requester-dispatch-1] DEBUG com.test.HTTP2Tester  - 1 <<[type=0, flags=1, streamId=1, payoad=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=267 lim=445 cap=65545]]
1186 [requester-dispatch-1] DEBUG com.test.HTTP2Tester  - 1 <<[type=0, flags=1, streamId=1, payoad=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=267 lim=445 cap=65545]]
1188 [requester-dispatch-1] INFO  com.test.HTTP2Tester  - Complete : /httpbin/ip->405 HTTP/2.0
1189 [requester-dispatch-1] DEBUG com.test.HTTP2Tester  - <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>405 Method Not Allowed</title>
<h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>
<p>The method is not allowed for the requested URL.</p>

1189 [main] INFO  com.test.HTTP2Tester  - Awaiting latch to countdown .... done
```

This is the log from when I point to my server. You can see it says it trusted the certificate so it must have connected and done some negotiation, but nothing happens after that.

```
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2021-03-04 14:51:36.352 GMT|SSLCipher.java:438|jdk.tls.keyLimits:  entry = AES/GCM/NoPadding KeyUpdate 2^37. AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE = 137438953472
0    [main] DEBUG com.test.HTTP2Tester  - Making requst to https://localhost:8003
54   [main] INFO  com.test.HTTP2Tester  - Awaiting latch to countdown ....
117  [requester-dispatch-1] INFO  com.test.HTTP2Tester  - Trusting certificate from EMAILADDRESS=john.fergus@......
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|0E|requester-dispatch-1|2021-03-04 14:51:37.145 GMT|Alert.java:238|Received alert message (
"Alert": {
  "level"      : "warning",
  "description": "close_notify"
}
)
182  [requester-dispatch-1] WARN  com.test.HTTP2Tester  - Failed : /VSFTestMT_Test/Test/Test_EchoHttpGet->org.apache.hc.core5.http.ConnectionClosedException: Connection is closed
183  [main] INFO  com.test.HTTP2Tester  - Awaiting latch to countdown .... done
```

This is the code.

```
    public void testWithHTTP2() throws Exception {
        
        final String testName = "testWithHTTP2";
        String content = "Code=99&Message=Goodbye";
        String contentType = "application.x_www_form_urlencoded";
        
        final SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom()
                .loadTrustMaterial(new TrustStrategy() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean isTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
                            throws CertificateException {
                        final X509Certificate cert = chain[0];
                        Log.info("Trusting certificate from "+cert.getSubjectDN());
                        return true;
                    }
                })
                .build();
        
        final TlsStrategy tlsStrategy = ClientTlsStrategyBuilder.create()
                .setSslContext(sslcontext)

                // IMPORTANT uncomment the following method when running Java 9 or older
                // in order for ALPN support to work and avoid the illegal reflective
                // access operation warning
                
                .setTlsDetailsFactory(new Factory<SSLEngine, TlsDetails>() {
                    @Override
                    public TlsDetails create(final SSLEngine sslEngine) {
                        return new TlsDetails(sslEngine.getSession(), sslEngine.getApplicationProtocol());
                    }
                })
                .build();

        final H2Config h2Config = H2Config.custom()
                .setPushEnabled(false)
                .build();
        
        HttpAsyncRequester requester = H2RequesterBootstrap.bootstrap()
                                .setH2Config(h2Config)
                                .setIOReactorConfig(IOReactorConfig.custom()
                                        .setSoTimeout(Timeout.ofSeconds(5))
                                        .build())
                                .setTlsStrategy(tlsStrategy)
                                .setVersionPolicy(HttpVersionPolicy.FORCE_HTTP_2)
                                .setStreamListener(new H2StreamListener() {

                                    //final FramePrinter framePrinter = new FramePrinter();

                                    private void logFrameInfo(final String prefix, final RawFrame frame) {
                                        Log.debug(prefix);
                                        Log.debug(frame.toString());
                                    }

                                    private void logFramePayload(final String prefix, final RawFrame frame) {
                                        Log.debug(prefix);
                                        Log.debug(frame.getPayload());
                                    }
                                     
                                    @Override
                                    public void onHeaderInput(final HttpConnection connection, final int streamId, final List<? extends Header> headers) {
                                        for (int i = 0; i < headers.size(); i++) {
                                            Log.debug(connection.getRemoteAddress() + " (" + streamId + ") << " + headers.get(i));
                                        }
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onHeaderOutput(final HttpConnection connection, final int streamId, final List<? extends Header> headers) {
                                        for (int i = 0; i < headers.size(); i++) {
                                            Log.debug(connection.getRemoteAddress() + " (" + streamId + ") >> " + headers.get(i));
                                        }
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onFrameInput(final HttpConnection connection, final int streamId, final RawFrame frame) {
                                        if (Log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                                            Log.debug(streamId + " <<" + frame);
                                        }
                                        if (Log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                                            Log.debug(streamId + " <<" + frame);
                                        }       
                                        }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onFrameOutput(final HttpConnection connection, final int streamId, final RawFrame frame) {
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onInputFlowControl(final HttpConnection connection, final int streamId, final int delta, final int actualSize) {
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onOutputFlowControl(final HttpConnection connection, final int streamId, final int delta, final int actualSize) {
                                    }

                                })
                                .create();
        
        CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        requester.start();

        // This tells me it trusts the cert, but get no further - just a "connection is closed" failure
        final HttpHost target = new HttpHost("https", "localhost", 8003);
        final String requestUri = "/VSFTestMT_Test/Test/Test_EchoHttpGet";

        // This works fine ... get a 405 saying POST is not allowed. 
//        final HttpHost target = new HttpHost("https", "nghttp2.org", 443);
//        final String requestUri = "/httpbin/ip";
        
        Log.debug("Making requst to "+target);
        final Future<AsyncClientEndpoint> future = requester.connect(target, Timeout.ofSeconds(5));
        final AsyncClientEndpoint clientEndpoint = future.get();
        final Future<Message<HttpResponse, String>> resultFuture1 = clientEndpoint.execute(
                new BasicRequestProducer(
                        Method.POST, target, requestUri, new StringAsyncEntityProducer(content, ContentType.create(contentType))),
                new BasicResponseConsumer<>(new StringAsyncEntityConsumer()),
                new FutureCallback<Message<HttpResponse, String>>() {

                    @Override
                    public void completed(final Message<HttpResponse, String> message) {
                        clientEndpoint.releaseAndReuse();
                        final HttpResponse response = message.getHead();
                        final String body = message.getBody();
                        Log.info("Complete : "+requestUri + "->" + response.getCode() + " " + response.getVersion());
                        Log.debug(body);
                        countDownLatch.countDown();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void failed(final Exception ex) {
                        clientEndpoint.releaseAndDiscard();
                        Log.warn("Failed : "+requestUri + "->" + ex);
                        countDownLatch.countDown();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void cancelled() {
                        clientEndpoint.releaseAndDiscard();
                        Log.warn("Cancelled : "+requestUri );
                        countDownLatch.countDown();
                    }

                });
        
        Log.info("Awaiting latch to countdown ....");
        countDownLatch.await();
        Log.info("Awaiting latch to countdown .... done");
        
        Message<HttpResponse, String> response = resultFuture1.get(); 
        Assert.assertNotNull(response);
        final HttpResponse response1 = response.getHead();
        final String entity1 = response.getBody();
        Assert.assertNotNull(response1);
        Assert.assertEquals(200, response1.getCode());
        assertTrue("Check we get Message Success back",response.getBody().contains("Success"));
        assertTrue("Check we get Message Goodbye back",response.getBody().contains("Goodbye"));


        Log.info("Shutting down I/O reactor");
        requester.initiateShutdown();

    }
```

Has anyone got any ideas how to debug the issue or resolve it? I think my Tomcat server setup is OK - is there anything or tool I can use to verify it is? Can I see any more debug/log info to find out why the connection is closed and what happened to close it?

Comment: Post the complete wire / context log of the session either here or to httpclient-users@hc.apache.org