# Apache HTTP Client 5.0 HTTP/2 POST Example needed

Tags: java, apache-httpcomponents, apache-httpclient-5.x

I can use CURL to send a HTTP/2 POST request with a payload to the `https://httpbin.org/post` as in the following example:

```
"c:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\curl" -v --http2 https://httpbin.org/post -d "arg1=param1&arg2=param2"
*   Trying 54.166.163.67:443...
* Connected to httpbin.org (54.166.163.67) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*  CAfile: c:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
*  CApath: none
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=httpbin.org
*  start date: Dec 21 00:00:00 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Jan 19 23:59:59 2022 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "httpbin.org" matched cert's "httpbin.org"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Amazon; OU=Server CA 1B; CN=Amazon
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x160f6b61d20)
> POST /post HTTP/2
> Host: httpbin.org
> user-agent: curl/7.75.0
> accept: */*
> content-length: 23
> content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 128)!
* We are completely uploaded and fine
< HTTP/2 200
< date: Fri, 05 Mar 2021 16:07:51 GMT
< content-type: application/json
< content-length: 453
< server: gunicorn/19.9.0
< access-control-allow-origin: *
< access-control-allow-credentials: true
<
{
  "args": {},
  "data": "",
  "files": {},
  "form": {
    "arg1": "param1",
    "arg2": "param2"
  },
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Content-Length": "23",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "User-Agent": "curl/7.75.0",
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-60425757-45ab281925b9b40e70398269"
  },
  "json": null,
  "origin": "51.37.211.242",
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/post"
}
* Connection #0 to host httpbin.org left intact
```

You can see it sends the arg1/arg2 parameters and they are in the echoed back response.

I would like to replicate that code in Java. I have had no luck myself doing it and cannot find an example of a HTTP/2 POST *with* a payload. There are some examples of GET/POST calls using HTTP/2 without a payload, and indeed I can write the code to make a request without a payload that works, but I cannot get the payload to send. If I use the same code but using HTTP/1 the payload is sent. Using `BasicRequestProducer` class you can give it producers (to send the request data I hope) and consumers (to consume the response) but the producer never seems to send the data.

See my other question on [HTTP/2 Connection Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66477744/how-to-troubleshoot-apache-client-5-0-connection-is-closed-https-post-error) for the sort of code I am using.

I have added some DEBUG to my examples and I can see the content/body being added to the request (or at least it looks to me like it is being added) so is there an issue with the correct formatting of the message?

```
188  [requester-dispatch-1] DEBUG com.test.HTTP2Tester  - Frame 1 >>[type=0, flags=0, streamId=1, payoad=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=23 cap=23]]
188  [requester-dispatch-1] DEBUG com.test.HTTP2Tester  - Frame info : Frame 1 >> [type=0, flags=0, streamId=1, payoad=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=23 cap=23]]
189  [requester-dispatch-1] DEBUG com.test.HTTP2Tester  - stream 1 frame: DATA (0x0); flags: (0x0); length: 23
189  [requester-dispatch-1] DEBUG com.test.HTTP2Tester  - Frame Payload : Frame 1 >> java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=23 cap=23]
189  [requester-dispatch-1] DEBUG com.test.HTTP2Tester  - Code=99&Message=  43 6f 64 65 3d 39 39 26 4d 65 73 73 61 67 65 3d
Goodbye           47 6f 6f 64 62 79 65

189  [requester-dispatch-1] DEBUG com.test.HTTP2Tester  - OutputFlow 0 >>0 -23 65512
190  [requester-dispatch-1] DEBUG com.test.HTTP2Tester  - OutputFlow 1 >>1 -23 65512
```

Can anyone give Java code to demonstrate a successful HTTP/2 POST with a payload????

Comment: Why are you not using a rest client instead of an HTTP client? Can easily use OkHttp for this type of need.

Comment: @AmimulEhsanRahi I want the full control of the HTTP client for other use cases. I am just using a simple example here to demonstrate my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the most simple form of a POST request that works the same way with HTTP/1.1 or HTTP/2 transports

```
final IOReactorConfig ioReactorConfig = IOReactorConfig.custom()
        .setSoTimeout(Timeout.ofSeconds(5))
        .build();

final CloseableHttpAsyncClient client = HttpAsyncClients.custom()
        .setIOReactorConfig(ioReactorConfig)
        .build();

client.start();

final HttpHost target = new HttpHost("nghttp2.org");
final String requestUri = "/httpbin/post";

final AsyncRequestProducer requestProducer = new BasicRequestProducer(Method.POST, target, requestUri,
        AsyncEntityProducers.create("stuff", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));
System.out.println("Executing POST request to " + requestUri);
final Future<Message<HttpResponse, String>> future = client.execute(
        requestProducer,
        new BasicResponseConsumer<String>(new StringAsyncEntityConsumer()),
        new FutureCallback<Message<HttpResponse, String>>() {

            @Override
            public void completed(final Message<HttpResponse, String> message) {
                System.out.println(requestUri + "->" + message.getHead().getCode());
                System.out.println(message.getBody());
            }

            @Override
            public void failed(final Exception ex) {
                System.out.println(requestUri + "->" + ex);
            }

            @Override
            public void cancelled() {
                System.out.println(requestUri + " cancelled");
            }

        });
future.get();

System.out.println("Shutting down");
client.close(CloseMode.GRACEFUL);
```

Here's application output including the header / context log of the session

```
Executing POST request to /httpbin/post
2021-03-07 17:10:10,379 DEBUG ex-0000000001 preparing request execution
2021-03-07 17:10:10,390 DEBUG ex-0000000001 Cookie spec selected: strict
2021-03-07 17:10:10,396 DEBUG ex-0000000001 Auth cache not set in the context
2021-03-07 17:10:10,396 DEBUG ex-0000000001 target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
2021-03-07 17:10:10,397 DEBUG ex-0000000001 proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
2021-03-07 17:10:10,399 DEBUG ex-0000000001 acquiring connection with route {s}->https://nghttp2.org:443
2021-03-07 17:10:10,399 DEBUG ex-0000000001 acquiring endpoint (3 MINUTES)
2021-03-07 17:10:10,401 DEBUG ex-0000000001 endpoint lease request (3 MINUTES) [route: {s}->https://nghttp2.org:443][total available: 0; route allocated: 0 of 5; total allocated: 0 of 25]
2021-03-07 17:10:10,406 DEBUG ex-0000000001 endpoint leased [route: {s}->https://nghttp2.org:443][total available: 0; route allocated: 1 of 5; total allocated: 1 of 25]
2021-03-07 17:10:10,406 DEBUG ex-0000000001 acquired ep-0000000000
2021-03-07 17:10:10,407 DEBUG ex-0000000001 acquired endpoint ep-0000000000
2021-03-07 17:10:10,407 DEBUG ep-0000000000 connecting endpoint (3 MINUTES)
2021-03-07 17:10:10,408 DEBUG ep-0000000000 connecting endpoint to https://nghttp2.org:443 (3 MINUTES)
2021-03-07 17:10:10,408 DEBUG https://nghttp2.org:443 resolving remote address
2021-03-07 17:10:10,410 DEBUG https://nghttp2.org:443 resolved to [nghttp2.org/139.162.123.134, nghttp2.org/2400:8902:0:0:f03c:91ff:fe69:a454]
2021-03-07 17:10:10,410 DEBUG https://nghttp2.org:443 connecting null to nghttp2.org/139.162.123.134:443 (3 MINUTES)
2021-03-07 17:10:10,722 DEBUG c-0000000000[ACTIVE][rc:c] protocol upgrade class org.apache.hc.core5.http2.impl.nio.ClientHttpProtocolNegotiator
2021-03-07 17:10:10,723 DEBUG https://nghttp2.org:443 connected c-0000000000 /192.168.8.105:55230->nghttp2.org/139.162.123.134:443
2021-03-07 17:10:10,725 DEBUG c-0000000000 start TLS
2021-03-07 17:10:10,769 DEBUG ep-0000000000 connected c-0000000000
2021-03-07 17:10:10,769 DEBUG ep-0000000000 endpoint connected
2021-03-07 17:10:10,769 DEBUG ex-0000000001 connected to target
2021-03-07 17:10:10,770 DEBUG ex-0000000001 route fully established
2021-03-07 17:10:10,770 DEBUG ex-0000000001 executing POST /httpbin/post HTTP/1.1
2021-03-07 17:10:10,771 DEBUG ep-0000000000 start execution ex-0000000001
2021-03-07 17:10:10,771 DEBUG ep-0000000000 executing exchange ex-0000000001 over c-0000000000
2021-03-07 17:10:10,772 DEBUG c-0000000000 RequestExecutionCommand with NORMAL priority
2021-03-07 17:10:10,773 DEBUG c-0000000000[ACTIVE][rwc:c][ACTIVE][rw][NOT_HANDSHAKING][0][0][0] Enqueued RequestExecutionCommand with priority IMMEDIATE
2021-03-07 17:10:10,773 DEBUG c-0000000000[ACTIVE][rw:c][ACTIVE][rw][NOT_HANDSHAKING][0][0][0] Event cleared [c]
2021-03-07 17:10:10,775 DEBUG Enabled protocols: [TLSv1.2]
2021-03-07 17:10:10,775 DEBUG Enabled cipher suites:[TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
2021-03-07 17:10:11,563 DEBUG Secure session established
2021-03-07 17:10:11,563 DEBUG  negotiated protocol: TLSv1.2
2021-03-07 17:10:11,564 DEBUG  negotiated cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
2021-03-07 17:10:11,565 DEBUG  peer principal: CN=nghttp2.org
2021-03-07 17:10:11,565 DEBUG  peer alternative names: [nghttp2.org, www.nghttp2.org]
2021-03-07 17:10:11,566 DEBUG  issuer principal: CN=R3, O=Let's Encrypt, C=US
2021-03-07 17:10:11,573 DEBUG c-0000000000[ACTIVE][rw:r][ACTIVE][rw][NOT_HANDSHAKING][62][0][0] Event set [w]
2021-03-07 17:10:11,575 DEBUG c-0000000000[ACTIVE][rw:r][ACTIVE][rw][NOT_HANDSHAKING][62][0][53] 24 bytes written
2021-03-07 17:10:11,575 DEBUG c-0000000000[ACTIVE][rw:r][ACTIVE][r][NOT_HANDSHAKING][62][0][53] Event cleared [w]
2021-03-07 17:10:11,606 DEBUG c-0000000000[ACTIVE][rw:r][ACTIVE][r][NOT_HANDSHAKING][62][0][53] protocol upgrade class org.apache.hc.core5.http2.impl.nio.ClientH2IOEventHandler
2021-03-07 17:10:11,608 DEBUG c-0000000000 >> stream 0 frame: SETTINGS (0x4); flags: (0x0); length: 36
2021-03-07 17:10:11,609 DEBUG c-0000000000[ACTIVE][rw:r][ACTIVE][r][NOT_HANDSHAKING][62][0][53] 0 bytes written
2021-03-07 17:10:11,609 DEBUG c-0000000000[ACTIVE][rw:r][ACTIVE][rw][NOT_HANDSHAKING][62][0][53] Event set [w]
2021-03-07 17:10:11,609 DEBUG c-0000000000[ACTIVE][rw:r][ACTIVE][rw][NOT_HANDSHAKING][62][0][53] Event set [w]
2021-03-07 17:10:11,609 DEBUG c-0000000000 << stream 0 flow control 2147418112 -> 2147483647
2021-03-07 17:10:11,609 DEBUG c-0000000000 << stream 0 flow control 2147483647 -> 2147483647
2021-03-07 17:10:11,609 DEBUG c-0000000000 >> stream 0 flow control 65535 -> 65535
2021-03-07 17:10:11,610 DEBUG c-0000000000 << stream 0 frame: SETTINGS (0x4); flags: (0x0); length: 24
2021-03-07 17:10:11,611 DEBUG c-0000000000 >> stream 0 flow control 983041 -> 1048576
2021-03-07 17:10:11,611 DEBUG c-0000000000[ACTIVE][rw:r][ACTIVE][rw][NOT_HANDSHAKING][62][33][53] Event set [w]
2021-03-07 17:10:11,611 DEBUG c-0000000000[ACTIVE][rw:r][ACTIVE][rw][NOT_HANDSHAKING][62][33][53] 0 bytes read
2021-03-07 17:10:11,611 DEBUG c-0000000000[ACTIVE][rw:r][ACTIVE][rw][NOT_HANDSHAKING][0][0][53] 0 bytes written
2021-03-07 17:10:11,614 DEBUG c-0000000000 << stream 1 flow control 65535 -> 65535
2021-03-07 17:10:11,614 DEBUG c-0000000000 >> stream 1 flow control 1048576 -> 1048576
2021-03-07 17:10:11,615 DEBUG ex-0000000001 send request POST /httpbin/post HTTP/1.1, entity len 5
2021-03-07 17:10:11,617 DEBUG c-0000000000 >> :method: POST
2021-03-07 17:10:11,617 DEBUG c-0000000000 >> :scheme: https
2021-03-07 17:10:11,617 DEBUG c-0000000000 >> :authority: nghttp2.org
2021-03-07 17:10:11,617 DEBUG c-0000000000 >> :path: /httpbin/post
2021-03-07 17:10:11,617 DEBUG c-0000000000 >> user-agent: Apache-HttpAsyncClient/5.1-beta2-SNAPSHOT (Java/1.8.0_282)
2021-03-07 17:10:11,617 DEBUG c-0000000000 >> content-type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
2021-03-07 17:10:11,620 DEBUG c-0000000000[ACTIVE][rw:r][ACTIVE][rw][NOT_HANDSHAKING][0][0][53] Event set [w]
2021-03-07 17:10:11,620 DEBUG ex-0000000001 produce request data
2021-03-07 17:10:11,620 DEBUG ex-0000000001 produce request data, len 5 bytes
2021-03-07 17:10:11,621 DEBUG c-0000000000[ACTIVE][rw:w][ACTIVE][rw][NOT_HANDSHAKING][0][0][74] 45 bytes written
2021-03-07 17:10:11,621 DEBUG c-0000000000 >> stream 0 frame: WINDOW_UPDATE (0x8); flags: (0x0); length: 4
2021-03-07 17:10:11,621 DEBUG c-0000000000[ACTIVE][rw:w][ACTIVE][rw][NOT_HANDSHAKING][0][0][74] 0 bytes written
2021-03-07 17:10:11,621 DEBUG ex-0000000001 produce request data
2021-03-07 17:10:11,621 DEBUG ex-0000000001 produce request data, len 5 bytes
2021-03-07 17:10:11,622 DEBUG c-0000000000[ACTIVE][rw:w][ACTIVE][rw][NOT_HANDSHAKING][0][0][42] 13 bytes written
2021-03-07 17:10:11,622 DEBUG c-0000000000 >> stream 0 frame: SETTINGS (0x4); flags: ACK (0x1); length: 0
2021-03-07 17:10:11,622 DEBUG c-0000000000[ACTIVE][rw:w][ACTIVE][rw][NOT_HANDSHAKING][0][0][42] 0 bytes written
2021-03-07 17:10:11,622 DEBUG ex-0000000001 produce request data
2021-03-07 17:10:11,622 DEBUG ex-0000000001 produce request data, len 5 bytes
2021-03-07 17:10:11,622 DEBUG c-0000000000[ACTIVE][rw:w][ACTIVE][rw][NOT_HANDSHAKING][0][0][38] 9 bytes written
2021-03-07 17:10:11,623 DEBUG c-0000000000 >> stream 1 frame: HEADERS (0x1); flags: END_HEADERS (0x4); length: 93
2021-03-07 17:10:11,623 DEBUG c-0000000000[ACTIVE][rw:w][ACTIVE][rw][NOT_HANDSHAKING][0][0][38] 0 bytes written
2021-03-07 17:10:11,623 DEBUG ex-0000000001 produce request data
2021-03-07 17:10:11,623 DEBUG ex-0000000001 produce request data, len 5 bytes
2021-03-07 17:10:11,623 DEBUG c-0000000000[ACTIVE][rw:w][ACTIVE][rw][NOT_HANDSHAKING][0][0][131] 102 bytes written
2021-03-07 17:10:11,623 DEBUG ex-0000000001 produce request data
2021-03-07 17:10:11,623 DEBUG ex-0000000001 produce request data, len 5 bytes
2021-03-07 17:10:11,623 DEBUG c-0000000000 >> stream 1 frame: DATA (0x0); flags: (0x0); length: 5
2021-03-07 17:10:11,624 DEBUG c-0000000000 >> stream 0 flow control -5 -> 1048571
2021-03-07 17:10:11,624 DEBUG c-0000000000 >> stream 1 flow control -5 -> 1048571
2021-03-07 17:10:11,624 DEBUG c-0000000000[ACTIVE][rw:w][ACTIVE][rw][NOT_HANDSHAKING][0][0][131] 0 bytes written
2021-03-07 17:10:11,624 DEBUG c-0000000000[ACTIVE][rw:w][ACTIVE][rw][NOT_HANDSHAKING][0][0][131] Event set [w]
2021-03-07 17:10:11,624 DEBUG ex-0000000001 end of request data
2021-03-07 17:10:11,624 DEBUG c-0000000000[ACTIVE][rw:w][ACTIVE][rw][NOT_HANDSHAKING][0][0][131] Event set [w]
2021-03-07 17:10:11,624 DEBUG c-0000000000[ACTIVE][rw:w][ACTIVE][rw][NOT_HANDSHAKING][0][0][43] 14 bytes written
2021-03-07 17:10:11,624 DEBUG c-0000000000 >> stream 1 frame: DATA (0x0); flags: END_STREAM (0x1); length: 0
2021-03-07 17:10:11,624 DEBUG c-0000000000[ACTIVE][rw:w][ACTIVE][rw][NOT_HANDSHAKING][0][0][43] 0 bytes written
2021-03-07 17:10:11,625 DEBUG c-0000000000[ACTIVE][rw:w][ACTIVE][rw][NOT_HANDSHAKING][0][0][38] 9 bytes written
2021-03-07 17:10:11,625 DEBUG c-0000000000[ACTIVE][rw:w][ACTIVE][r][NOT_HANDSHAKING][0][0][38] Event cleared [w]
2021-03-07 17:10:11,968 DEBUG c-0000000000 << stream 0 frame: SETTINGS (0x4); flags: ACK (0x1); length: 0
2021-03-07 17:10:11,969 DEBUG c-0000000000[ACTIVE][rw:r][ACTIVE][rw][NOT_HANDSHAKING][38][9][0] Event set [w]
2021-03-07 17:10:11,969 DEBUG c-0000000000[ACTIVE][rw:r][ACTIVE][rw][NOT_HANDSHAKING][38][9][0] 0 bytes read
2021-03-07 17:10:11,970 DEBUG c-0000000000 << stream 1 frame: HEADERS (0x1); flags: END_HEADERS (0x4); length: 231
2021-03-07 17:10:11,971 DEBUG c-0000000000 << :status: 200
2021-03-07 17:10:11,971 DEBUG c-0000000000 << date: Sun, 07 Mar 2021 16:10:11 GMT
2021-03-07 17:10:11,971 DEBUG c-0000000000 << content-type: application/json
2021-03-07 17:10:11,971 DEBUG c-0000000000 << content-length: 382
2021-03-07 17:10:11,971 DEBUG c-0000000000 << access-control-allow-origin: *
2021-03-07 17:10:11,971 DEBUG c-0000000000 << access-control-allow-credentials: true
2021-03-07 17:10:11,971 DEBUG c-0000000000 << x-backend-header-rtt: 0.003465
2021-03-07 17:10:11,971 DEBUG c-0000000000 << strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000
2021-03-07 17:10:11,971 DEBUG c-0000000000 << server: nghttpx
2021-03-07 17:10:11,971 DEBUG c-0000000000 << via: 1.1 nghttpx
2021-03-07 17:10:11,971 DEBUG c-0000000000 << alt-svc: h3-29=":443"; ma=3600
2021-03-07 17:10:11,972 DEBUG c-0000000000 << x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
2021-03-07 17:10:11,972 DEBUG c-0000000000 << x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
2021-03-07 17:10:11,972 DEBUG c-0000000000 << x-content-type-options: nosniff
2021-03-07 17:10:11,975 DEBUG ex-0000000001 consume response HTTP/2.0 200 OK, entity len -1
2021-03-07 17:10:11,978 DEBUG c-0000000000 << stream 1 frame: DATA (0x0); flags: END_STREAM (0x1); length: 382
2021-03-07 17:10:11,979 DEBUG c-0000000000 << stream 1 flow control -382 -> 65153
2021-03-07 17:10:11,979 DEBUG c-0000000000 << stream 0 flow control -382 -> 2147483265
2021-03-07 17:10:11,979 DEBUG ex-0000000001 consume response data, len 382 bytes
2021-03-07 17:10:11,979 DEBUG ex-0000000001 end of response data
Shutting down
/httpbin/post->200
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "stuff", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1", 
    "Host": "nghttp2.org", 
    "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked", 
    "User-Agent": "Apache-HttpAsyncClient/5.1-beta2-SNAPSHOT (Java/1.8.0_282)"
  }, 
  "json": null, 
  "origin": "213.55.225.170", 
  "url": "https://nghttp2.org/httpbin/post"
}

2021-03-07 17:10:11,980 DEBUG ex-0000000001 message exchange successfully completed
2021-03-07 17:10:11,980 DEBUG ep-0000000000 releasing valid endpoint
2021-03-07 17:10:11,980 DEBUG Shutdown GRACEFUL
2021-03-07 17:10:11,981 DEBUG ep-0000000000 releasing endpoint
2021-03-07 17:10:11,981 DEBUG ep-0000000000 connection c-0000000000 can be kept alive for 3 MINUTES
2021-03-07 17:10:11,982 DEBUG ep-0000000000 connection released [route: {s}->https://nghttp2.org:443][total available: 1; route allocated: 1 of 5; total allocated: 1 of 25]
2021-03-07 17:10:11,982 DEBUG c-0000000000[ACTIVE][rw:r][ACTIVE][rw][NOT_HANDSHAKING][698][631][0] Event set [w]
2021-03-07 17:10:11,982 DEBUG c-0000000000[ACTIVE][rw:r][ACTIVE][rw][NOT_HANDSHAKING][698][631][0] 0 bytes read
2021-03-07 17:10:11,982 DEBUG c-0000000000[ACTIVE][r:r][ACTIVE][r][NOT_HANDSHAKING][0][0][0] Event cleared [w]
2021-03-07 17:10:11,983 DEBUG c-0000000000[ACTIVE][rw:r][ACTIVE][rw][NOT_HANDSHAKING][0][0][0] Enqueued ShutdownCommand with priority IMMEDIATE
2021-03-07 17:10:11,983 DEBUG c-0000000000[ACTIVE][r:w][ACTIVE][r][NOT_HANDSHAKING][0][0][0] Event cleared [w]
2021-03-07 17:10:11,984 DEBUG c-0000000000 >> stream 0 frame: GOAWAY (0x7); flags: (0x0); length: 25
2021-03-07 17:10:11,985 DEBUG c-0000000000[ACTIVE][r:w][ACTIVE][r][NOT_HANDSHAKING][0][0][63] 34 bytes written
2021-03-07 17:10:11,985 DEBUG c-0000000000[ACTIVE][rw:w][ACTIVE][rw][NOT_HANDSHAKING][0][0][63] Event set [w]
2021-03-07 17:10:11,985 DEBUG c-0000000000[ACTIVE][rw:w][ACTIVE][rw][NOT_HANDSHAKING][0][0][63] Close GRACEFUL
2021-03-07 17:10:12,275 DEBUG Shutdown connection pool GRACEFUL
2021-03-07 17:10:12,275 DEBUG c-0000000000 Shutdown connection GRACEFUL
2021-03-07 17:10:12,275 DEBUG Connection pool shut down
```

Comment: Thank you. I have taken your answer and can get it to work with the server you are hitting at nghttp2.org. I can also point it to my server - a Tomcat 9 with a simple JSP page echoing the request parameters. My servlet works with a CURL request, but not from the java code. From the server-side debug logs I can see the request in both is almost identical, but the CURL request sends a content-length header while the Java does not.  If I add a content-length header to the java it works - so it seems the server requires it. Is this a bug/defect with either the java client or the tomcat server?

Comment: @JohnFergus In my opinion `content-length` is not required and is basically useless with HTTP/2 protocol. As far as I am concerned this is most likely a server side issue.